# Prereload script into node interactive mode

Tags: node.js

Is it possibille to run node.exe, pipe a text into it, and continue the interactive session?

I want to create a shortcut bat (or bash) file for editing my database.

Usually this is what I'm doing:

```
$ node

>var db=require('mydb')
>db.open('myserver')
>//Now I can start access the db
>db.query...
```

I want to do something like that:

```
$ node -i perDefinedDb.js

>db.query(.... //I don't want to define the DB each time I run the node.exe
```

I tried some like that:

```
echo console.log(a) | node.exe
```

This is the result:

```
3
```

And the program is Finish. I want to continue the node REPL after piping something into.

---

**In Other Words:**
I want to be able to use my DB from node REPL, without defining it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the REPL from your js file and you can give the context you want:

```
const repl = require('repl');
var db = require('mydb');
db.open('myserver');

repl.start('> ').context.db = db;
```

Now you just have to run this file (`node myREPL.js`) and you can REPL as usual.

Comment: Wow. So easy. very good idea to use the repl module for that. Thank's